# Creation of UIAlertController on ViewWillAppear gives warning

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I was trying to create a `UIAlertController` on `ViewWillAppear`, it was giving me the below warning.

```
"Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f8798c15df0> on <ViewController: 0x7f8798f81450> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!".
```

My Understanding it is ready to show the view to the user in `ViewWillAppear`, but fairly expensive.

However when i moved the same `UIAlertController` code to `ViewDidAppear` it was showing the Alert Msg. 
Can you please clarify whey the alert msg is not getting show in `ViewWillAppear`.

Comment: put it into the `–viewDidAppear:` method, the statement is correct, you view is not in the view hierarchy when the `–viewWillAppear:` method invoked.

Comment: same error in viewdidappear

Answer (score 3):

`UIAlertController` is unlike the typical `UIAlertView`, which inherited from UIView. Adding a `UIView` in `viewDidLoad`, appear, etc. is no problem because you are adding it that view controller's view hierarchy.

Now, with `UIAlertController`, it's a first class view controller. This means that you should present it the same way you would other view controllers - all the same rules apply.

In `viewWillAppear`, the view controller isn't done being added to the window's hierarchy, so it's a poor choice to present the alert controller. As you found, `viewDidAppear` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

`viewWillAppear:` is not a good location to present another view controller since the current one being presented is not yet in the window hierarchy and is also in a transition animation. You should either use `viewDidAppear:` or add a slight delay before displaying the alert controller.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers on here cover the topic pretty well, I just wanted to add additional details. It typically is not problematic to add child view controllers in `viewWillAppear:` or even `viewDidLoad:`. In fact if you use a container view controller in IB then it will be integrated before either of these are called.

The problem is more so to do specifically with the alert controller. Alert controllers function on a different window hierarchy than your typical UI (think Z axis) and manipulate the UI in a more intensive way than a standard container (since it is not a container).

In order for the alert to properly present it must happen after the current view is displayed (there could be a number of reasons here). This is why presenting it in `viewDidAppear:` worked (since the current vc's view will be fully live).

Answer (score 0):

The same error may occur if parameters of `UIAlertController` are `nil`, such as `title`, `message`